# merging two set of array values into one multidimesional array

Tags: php, arrays

i'm a newbie in programming and in php too and i was wondering if anyone can help me with my array problem.

i have two set of array, example:

```
$name = array("peter","peter","joe");  
$cars = array("ford", "gmc", "mercy");
```

and i would like to merge them into a multidimensional array like this

```
$merge = array(array($name[0], $cars[0]),array($name[1], $cars[1]),array($name[2], $cars[2]));
```

now, i would like keep the structure as above but i would like to do it with a native array function or foreach function.

i've tried `array_merge` and `array_combine` but it didn't turn out as i expected.
i've tried `$arr3 = $name + $cars;` but it didn't work too

does anyone can help me on what function should i use?

many thanks
~aji

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) sounds like what you are looking for. See "Example #4 Creating an array of arrays"

> An interesting use of this function is to construct an array of arrays, which can be easily performed by using NULL  as the name of the callback function

```
$merged = array_map(NULL, $name, $cars);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = array("peter","peter","joe");
$cars = array("ford", 'gm$c', "mercy");
for($i=0;$i<count($name);$i++){
  $array[$i]=array($name[$i],$cars[$i]);
}
print_r($array);
```